# What console is this light gun and controller from?

Tags: controllers, hardware-identification

[image: controlers]

Can you identify the early gaming system these controllers were shipped with?

What I remember is that the two hand units (essentially rotary encoders) and the light-gun hooked up to a CRT TV via a base-station. I think it was some magnavox odyssey clone. The console thing was bought in Europe, I believe circa 1981.

Comment: I just want to give kudos for an 'identification' question that actually follows Arqade's identification guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to say that they are from a [Conic](http://retroconsoles.wikia.com/wiki/Conic) TVG 406-6.

[image: console]
<sub>[Image Source](https://picclick.es/Consola-Conic-Tvg-406-6-Color-Video-Spiel-6-262515766965.html)</sub>

A lot of web pages that pop up for this are in what appears to be a European language (Spanish according to Google). I can't find much, but maybe this is from Spain which is in Europe.  I also note that there appears to be a bunch of models of this particular console which may have different (but similar) controllers, but this one featured both the white dial controller and light gun.

Comment: I can't remember the console's shape, but i do remember these two pale red and blue buttons. So you found it! Thanks. Answer accepted.